# Common code for all actions and views in Play Framework project

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.5

I want to show current authenticated user on every page of my web project.
I use the `@Security.Authenticated` annotation to restrict user access. 
I have an authorize logic (method) that retrieves the current user data form DB using `user_id` session value.

So, there are a few problems to solve:

1. Where should I place `getCurrentUser()` method in order to execute it before all actions of all controllers?
2. How to make the `currentUser` value available in all views?
3. How to skip the authentication for certain actions?

What I have now is working just for one action. I don't want to repeat this code for other actions? I need it to work for the whole project:

- execute `getCurrentUser()` before all actions in order to get `currentUser` value;
- make `currentUser` value available in the view

Controller:

```
@Security.Authenticated(Secured.class)
public class UsersController extends Controller {

    public Result index() {
        return ok(index.render(getCurrentUser()));
    }

    private User getCurrentUser() {
        return User.find.byId(Long.parseLong(request().username()));
    }
}
```

View (index.scala.html):

```
@(currentUser: User)

<p>Hello, @currentUser.name</p>
```

I am going to place this view code into `main.scala.html` file which is shared by all views.

Comment: There's filters as middleware, you might be able to use these.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**For part 1 of your question:**
With a Play HTTP Filter you can intercept every http request.  You may want ot read [this](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/JavaHttpFilters).

**For part 2 of your question:** It really depends on what precisely you want to gain by keeping "currentUser" in memory.  Do you want to keep a POJO in memory?  Or just a String representation (potentially JSON) of your user? And for how long?

If you want a POJO, you may want to use Http.Context.args.  This allows you to store a Map into memory.  However, this is only valid PER request.  Here's the [JavaDoc](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.5/api/java/play/mvc/Http.Context.html).

There are other mechanisms to keep strings in memory longer. You can use the Flash or Session Scope found at: www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/JavaSessionFlash.

Flash scope keeps a string in memory until the session's NEXT request.  The session scope lasts as long as a session (which can be longer than you expect at times), because there is no technical timeout for a session.  These strings could potentially be JSON, if that helps.

There is another alternative to storing POJOs longer than an http request. It's the Play cache API. You can read more about it here:  www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/JavaCache.

You CAN also implement your own custom cache as well.

Finally, you can also use an API endpoint to retrieve the USER.  This might be expensive, but that depends.  You might also use this approach in conjunction with a cache of some sort.

Some questions to consider:

1. What is the minimum representation I need to keep in memory?
2. What is the minimum amount of time I need to keep this is memory?
3. What form of representation do I want? String? JSON? POJO?
4. Who needs access to this representation?  Client? Server?

P.S.  I have a low rep, so I can't post more than 2 links at a time.  That's why some "links" are posted as text.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try this. I need `currentUser` to persist per request and it must be POJO. And I need to access it from controllers and views.

Comment: I didn't create filters since I had already had one which is  `@Security.Authenticated`. I moved my logic there and stored `currentUser` in `Http.Context.args`. Thank you for your help @dwayne-predictable-data !

Comment: @chumakoff Do you mind sharng an example on how to do this?